# memory leak in catching website

Tags: memory-leaks, vbscript

I manage to create some simple script to capture news form website, but problem is in memory leak. It seems that script doesn't release memory :(
I tried to close, empty (nothing instead empty doesn't help)-check end lines.

```
Do While x<50000
  Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
  WScript.Sleep 60000
  oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", "http://www.news.com/sport", False
  WScript.Sleep 900
  oXMLHTTP.Send

  If oXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
    Set html = CreateObject("HTMLfile")
    html.write oXMLHTTP.responseText
    ...some code...

  html=Empty
  oXMLHTTP=Empty
  oXMLHTTP.responseText=Empty
  oXMLHTTP.close
  oStream.close
  oStream=Empty
Loop
```

Answer (score 2):

1. You need `Set x = Nothing` to release object `x`
2. You must not access members of an object you released before (oXMLHTTP)

Answer (score 1):

In next script stub:

- `oXMLHTTP` variable is declared *global* and defined once for use in the entire script;
- `html` and `oStream` variables are local to the `DoSomething` procedure  and are released out of it...

However, some statements stay unclear for me...

```
Option Explicit
Dim x, oXMLHTTP
Set oXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.3.0")
Do While x<50000
  WScript.Sleep 60000
  oXMLHTTP.Open "GET", "http://www.news.com/sport", False
  WScript.Sleep 900
  oXMLHTTP.Send
  DoSomething
  oXMLHTTP.close
Loop

Sub DoSomething
  Dim html, oStream
  If oXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
     Set html = CreateObject("HTMLfile")
     html.write oXMLHTTP.responseText
     '...some code...
  End If
  '...another code...
End Sub
```

> [Local Variables in Sub Procedures](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tt223ahx(v=vs.84).aspx)
>
> The values of local variables in a Sub procedure are not preserved
>   between calls to the procedure.
>
> Variables that are explicitly declared in a procedure (using Dim or
>   the equivalent) are always local to the procedure. Variables that are
>   used but not explicitly declared in a procedure are also local, unless
>   they are explicitly declared at some higher level outside the
>   procedure.
>
> If variables are not explicitly declared in a procedure, a naming
>   conflict can occur if anything you have defined at the script level
>   has a duplicate name. If your procedure refers to an undeclared
>   variable that has the same name as another procedure, constant or
>   variable, it is assumed that your procedure is referring to that
>   script-level name. To avoid this kind of conflict, use an [Option
>   Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bw9t3484(v=vs.84).aspx) Statement to force explicit declaration of variables.

[Scope and Lifetime of Variables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz(v=vs.84).aspx)

> A variable's scope is determined by where you declare it. When you
>   declare a variable within a procedure, only code within that procedure
>   can access or change the value of that variable. It has local scope
>   and is a procedure-level variable. If you declare a variable outside a
>   procedure, you make it recognizable to all the procedures in your
>   script. This is a script-level variable, and it has script-level
>   scope.
>
> The lifetime of a variable depends on how long it exists. The lifetime
>   of a script-level variable extends from the time it is declared until
>   the time the script is finished running. At procedure level, a
>   variable exists only as long as you are in the procedure. When the
>   procedure exits, the variable is destroyed. Local variables are ideal
>   as temporary storage space when a procedure is executing. You can have
>   local variables of the same name in several different procedures
>   because each is recognized only by the procedure in which it is
>   declared.